# Solr nGram Filter minGramSize - token for word with only 2 characters

Tags: solr, lucene

I am working with Solr and would like to understand how EdgeNGramFilterFactory works.

For example, I am searching for a term "1 tb". Pls note that I have few products with attributes for the fields I'm search on.

Here is the filter applied on Index time for this fieldtype.

```
<filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="10" />
```

Now, when I search for the term "1 tb", I do not get desired results.

I have few products with term "5 MegaPixels" and when I search for "5 meg" it gives me result. Later I found it does not work for "5 me". And does not give results.

If I remove nGram filter, it works fine. Moreover, if we set minGramSize ="1", then query "1 tb" works fine.

I was assuming that for term tb, the token tb should be valid. But it seems that it is not created when I apply minGramSize of 2!

Can someone explain why?

Here is the field defined in schema.

```
<fieldType name="AttributesField" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="10" /> 
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Comment: did you analyse the same on solr admin page? What'd the exact fieldType used for the field?

Comment: I created text field type to apply separate filters and tokenizers required.

Comment: Can you describe the same? what all it has?

Comment: hi, added to the question

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with the below fieldType

```
<fieldType name="AttributesField" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="10" /> 
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

`PorterStemFilterFactory` : it does normalization process that removes common endings from words.

```
Example: "riding", "rides", "horses" ==> "ride", "ride", "hors".

<filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" side="front"/>
```

With the configuration below the string value **`Nigerian`** gets broken down to the following terms

```
Nigerian => "ni", "nig", "nige", "niger", "nigeri", "nigeria", "nigeria", "nigerian"
```

Comment: I tried this, got same result. How can I check what tokens are made?

Comment: Check the same on solr analysis page..it will show the tokens created at the time of indexing and tokens sent at the time of query

Comment: http://hostname:8983/solr/.............https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Query+Screen

Comment: Can you check with the current fieldType ...I have modified the same changed the tokenizer...

Comment: Pls advise what did you changed?

Comment: I have changed the tokenizer from "StandardTokenizerFactory" to "KeywordTokenizerFactory".